# Does the MD5 algorithm always generate the same output for the same string?

Tags: hash, md5

Does the MD5 algorithm always generate the same output for the same string?

Is using a salt the only to produce different output?

Comment: Can you explain why you ask?  It seems like you want another behavior for some reason.

Comment: It is a deterministic algorithm. How could it do otherwise?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the differences between cryptography and hashing.

I think also had it mixed up RC5

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes, otherwise MD5 would be useless for things like file verification. What reason would you have for non deterministic output?

Comment: I laughed at "What reason would you have for non deterministic output" because that is my thought exactly. However, apparently .NET's GetHashCode() _is_ non-deterministic, at least between application runs.

Comment: In C#, MD5 is an interface, and MD5CryptoServiceProvider and MD5Cng are two separate implementations. That's weird if they're both deterministic.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, MD5 always outputs the same given the same input.  That's how it's used for passwords.  You store the hash in the database, then when the user types their password in, it's hashed again and the two hashes are compared.

NOTE: MD5 is not recommended for hashing passwords because it's cryptographically weak.  There are more suitable cryptographic hashes available, such as [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).  However, historically, it has been used for this purpose.

Comment: MD5 shouldn't be used for passwords, never.

Comment: @mavnaranjo: Don't think it warrants a downvote.  I'm not wrong, and that was 5 years ago.  It -was- and -is- used for passwords, as insecure as that might be, and it is still a valid illustrative point for how you know it has an invariant output.  I will add an edit to that point though.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, a hash algorithm always produces the same output. If you use the same salt, this will also always produce the same output for a given input.

Answer (score 1):

Yes MD5 is deterministic, and this is considered a desirable characteristic for many applications of message digest functions.

As for using a salt, by that you really mean 'changing the input string in some subtle way' don't you ?  And, of course, it is also a desirable characteristic of message digests that they produce (with very high probability) a different digest for a different message.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. MD5 is a hash function.

This does *not* mean that an MD5 is unique. Multiple inputs could map to the same hash, but any given input has only one hash.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Although in some cases it creates the same hash for different strings.

Comment: I'm afraid same answer appeared earlier. 9 years earlier.